# why is the memory card not functioning properly?

Tags: sd-card, corruption

I have a 32 GB memory card (SD card) which I am using via card reader. I have formatted it as fat32 but it is not working. The memory card isn't running on music systems.
Please look at the error as shown in the screen-shot of `gparted`.

[image]

When in gparted, I right clicked the media and selected the option "Information", a screen popped-up as shown below.
[image]

In gparted I right clicked the media and selected option "check and repair". The output screen shot is below but the issue persists.

[image]

Is it hardware issue? How to resolve it?